# How To Color Lines In A Pattern (from SubtlePatterns)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, patterns

I found a pattern on SubtlePatterns:

[image]

I've seen how to change the overall/colour - but what I want to do is recolor only the the lines to a yellow.

Any tips on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As with most things there are countless ways you could do this.

The quickest and easiest that comes to mind: add a gradient map. This gives you the benefit of easily being able to change the color of both lines and background. There isn't much contrast in the image so you need to bunch both gradient color stops to one end.

This took me all of about 10 seconds:

[image: Gradient Map]

Answer (score 2):

Put a Color Overlay on top of the pattern then use the Layer Style Blend-If function:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. In this particular instance I'd try the following steps. 
First make a background layer with the light grey color in the pattern. 
Take the image layer and play around with brightness/contrast until you get a black and white image. (try and find the right balance... Pushing it to the extremes can,  result in distortion of shape and anti-aliasing issues.)

Now goto Select> Color Range. 
Select the white area. 
Delete. 
Now simply apply a color overlay layer style.

P.s.  You could skip the whole brightness/contrast part, but I feel it just makes the work cleaner and easier.

Comment: Hi - I can't turn that already grey image into black and white

Answer (score -1):

I think you're better off finding that pattern in vector and changing the colors. It's a pretty common pattern, and just googling "scallop pattern vector" brings up several free & paid options that are pretty similar.